# Flink SQL : Use changelog stream to update rows in Dynamic Table

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a stream that contains JSON messages that look like this :

```
{"operation":"CREATE","data":{"id":"id-1", "value":"value-1"}}
{"operation":"CREATE","data":{"id":"id-2", "value":"value-2"}}
{"operation":"DELETE","data":{"id":"id-1"}}
{"operation":"UPDATE","data":{"id":"id-2", "value":"value-3"}}
```

This stream is handled in a `DataStream<Row>` that is registered as a `TableSource`.

I want to use this stream as a **changelog stream** to update the content of a Flink Table, but I can't find a way to do that.

I have defined a `StreamTableSource` as :

```
public class MyTableSource implements StreamTableSource<Row>, ... {

    @Override
    public DataStream<Row> getDataStream(final StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        DataStream<Row> stream = getDataStream(env) // Retrieve changelog stream 
                .keyBy([SOME KEY])                  // Aggregate by key 
                .map(new MyMapFunction());          // Map the update message with the correct encoding ?

        return stream;
    }

    ... 
}
```

And this `TableSource` is used in

```
public void process(final StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
    final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

    tableEnv.registerTableSource("MyTableSource", new MyTableSource());

    Table result = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTableSource"); // This table content should be updated according to operation described in the changelog stream.

    result.insertInto([SOME SINK]);
}
```

What is the good way to do this ? (And more specificaly, how can I use a stream to delete rows from a Table ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the internal changelog processing capabilities are not exposed through the API. So there is no source available that allows you to interpret an incoming changelog as a table. This is planned for [Flink 1.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15331).

Until then, you could think about using a user-defined aggregate function that applies the updates as proposed here:

[Apache Flink: How to enable "upsert mode" for dynamic tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554999/apache-flink-how-to-enable-upsert-mode-for-dynamic-tables?rq=1)